# Square brackets after float4 vector type

Tags: cuda, extern, gpu-shared-memory

I'm studying a CUDA tutorial and at a some point the shared memory is dynamically allocated like so:

```
extern __shared__ float4[] buffer;
```

It seems to be quite simple to understand except for the square brackets `[]` after the vector type `float4`. What do they mean? why should I write them?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared) may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used for a dynamic shared memory and the proper way is :

```
extern __shared__ float4 buffer[]
```

, not

```
extern __shared__ float4[] buffer
```

When you use this ,you must also use the size of the allocated memory in the kernel call:

```
size_t blockSize = theBlockSize * theBlockSize
myfunc<<< NbBlocks, NbThreadsPerBlock , sizeof(float4) * blockSize>>>
```

Comment: ok but what's wrong with the second way you wrote? what would that mean?

Comment: what's wrong with the second way is that the compiler will throw an error.

Comment: @Federico Gentile:It's what Robert Crovella write.The type of your data is of float4 .The data is the 'buffer'.I think in java you can wirte  for example 'int [] buffer' but in c you can't.